# node.js postgres query methods

Tags: node.js, postgresql

For the postgres npm package, I don't understand the difference between these 2 ways of executing a query (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg):

1) Passing the query to a pool
2) Borrowing a client from a pool and executing the query with it

The author says that method #2 is for transactions. Does that mean if I want to execute multiple sql queries and I want them all to either execute or not, I have to use method #2?

If yes, then what happens if one query executes and the other one gives an error. Does the package or postgres undo the first query that was successful?

Comment: Post some code and you are more likely to get a response.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

Comment: If you switch over to [pg-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise), then you won't care about any of that connection mess.

Answer (score 1):

The one whos undoes the first transaction is postgreSQL. Not the pg package nor nothing inside node.js.

If you are confortable with Promises use `pg-promise` module of @vitaliy-t.

If you are not confortable with Promises put that in your TODO list. Promises simplify all asyncrhonic stufs.